# Calling authenticated web service from windows mobile app - need access to cookie container

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-mobile, cookies

I'm writing a Windows mobile client that needs to call a web service.

The web service has a login method that returns a session id in a cookie.

I've written a quick test app using normal winforms and I can access the web service cookiecontainer property without any problem

In my windows mobile project (C# .net 2.0 targeting windows mobile professional 6.0) I can reference in the web service as a web reference but there's no cookiecontainer property on the proxy class created for my web service.

Is there any way to get the cookie back so that I can save it and send the session id cookie back with subsequent requests?

**[edit 1]**

If not, is there a better way to handle authentication on the web service rather than piggy-backing on the existing asp.net website's membership and using sessions?